# Window is not recognizing an application resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm-light

To reproduce the error:

Create a new MVVM-Light WPF application.

Copy MainWindow.xaml to MainWindow2.xaml Rename MainWindow2's class name to MainWindow2 (and the constructor)

Rename MainWindow2 window class attribute to "x:Class="MvvmLight2.MainWindow2"

Remove StartupUri from App.xaml

Add the following to App:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    new MainWindow().Show();
    new MainWindow2().Show();
}
```

Run the application and get error:

```
Cannot find resource named '{Locator}'. Resource names are case sensitive.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' in markup file 'MvvmLight2;component/mainwindow.xaml' Line 10 Position 9.
```

To resolve the error:
Remove DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" from both windows.

Add the following line to both windows' constructors:

```
DataContext = new ViewModelLocator().Main;
```

The application now runs.

The question is why doesn't it recognize the Locator even though it's defined as an application resource?

**Update:**

I just noticed that I can add the same resource on both xaml and code without any visible side effects. The question now becomes, is there a problem with this? Does it create a duplicate resource or it doesn't because they have the same key? 
More than just hacking it, I'm trying to understand what's going on.

Comment: what happens if you put `base.OnStartup(e)` BEFORE `new MainWindow().Show()`?

Comment: Get the same error before, after, and without it.

Comment: why don't you just add the resource in the `OnStartup` override (instead of app.xaml), before showing the windows?

Comment: The resource has the attribute d:IsDataSource="True" to make it easier to design with. How can I set this attribute in code? (resource dictionary only accepts a key and a value)

Comment: ok, one thing about Visual Studio **designer** it does NOT run the `App.xaml.cs` code-behind file (only the `App.xaml` markup). So, you should be able to keep the `App.xaml` markup for design-time then in `OnStartup`: `Resources.Add("Locator", new ViewModelLocator())`'

Comment: also, I'm not completely familiar with d:IsDataSource, so you may have to come up with a work-around if it's trying to add the resource twice during run-time

Answer (score 4):

Managed to fix this by adding `InitializeComponent()` inside `Application.Startup` event handler:

### App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="SomeNamespace.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup"> <!-- Important to use Startup -->
```

## App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // <-- Important to set this!

        var window = new MainWindow();

        window.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a superstar. The key here is InitializeComponent(). I had a splash screen and had to initiliaze from a custom method. Thanks a lot. Now i can go to sleep tonight :)

Comment: @SabbirHassan :-) glad it helpd, you know you can upvote answer ;-)

Comment: I am so sorry. I thought i did it. But anyway i have done it just now. Thanks

Comment: Geez... found this and it solved an entire day of issues with app.xaml... I'm late but... thank you so much!